# Retrieve information from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I found this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ and author used this code to retrieve information from database:

```
Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }
```

Can somebody explain me what does this piece of code mean:

```
Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact is a **POJO** class with three properties

```
int _id;
String _name;
String _phone_number;
```

That line is nothing but instantiating `Contact` class with its Constructor having three parameters for initialization of it's fields.

And finally [`cursor.getString(0)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)) means retrieving value of the requested column as a `String` from the [`cursor`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) object. And parameter `0` is an integer which represents the index of column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, `0` is referenced to `KEY_ID`, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are absolute !! (Y) that is passed for setting `_id` property of that class

Answer (score 1):

Creating contact object by passing id, name and phone number.
This method is fetching that particular contact row from database by matching the id passed as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Contact is a model class that the author has created. I am guessing the contact model has 3 fields. One int that denotes the id and Strings for name and phone number.

The line of code is just creating a new object of model class with details fetched from database in that order. The Contact class is as below

```
public class Contact{

    int id;
    String phoneNumber,name;

  void Contact(id,phoneNumber,name){
     this.id=id;
     this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
     this.name=name;
   }
 }
```